# How to fix 'sqlite-3.7.2-sqlitejdbc.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform'

Tags: java, sqlite, spatialite

I want to load sqlite spatialfunction ,so I execute 
stmt.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')");
then I get the error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\17222\AppData\Local\Temp\sqlite-3.7.2-sqlitejdbc.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

I try to delete sqlite-3.7.2-sqlitejdbc.dll and download a 64-bite function and put in the file.But when I run the code again ,I found that the sqlite-3.7.2-sqlitejdbc.dll(32-bite version) will generate by the code ,and it will cover the download one.

In fact I've run it successfully run it in same machine before. It can execute some spatial sql function ,but when I new a project and repeat it ,the error appears.

here some code :

```
    String path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
    System.out.println(path);
    // 加载JDBC
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");


    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        // absolutely required by SpatiaLite
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        config.enableLoadExtension(true);

        // create a database connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3290000\\OrgDBForCheck.db3",
                config.toProperties());
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setQueryTimeout(30);

        // loading SpatiaLite
        stmt.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')");

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT aswkt(geometry)\n" +
                " FROM AD_HP\n" +
                "where X(Geometry)>120\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your sqlite jar file only content the 32 bit .dll
You can check if it has two .dll for both 32 and 64 bits versions.

here is the link to download correct driver jar file https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/